# What is the best open source grid for asp.net mvc 3 with full functionality?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, datagrid, datagridview

My Requirements are as follows:

1. I don't want to pay for the control.
2. I want fully functional grid with server side paging, sorting, filtering, inline editing, searching, grouping etc.
3. I don't want to code much in jquery, rather would prefer to code in c#.

Based on the above requirements, what will be the best option for asp.net mvc 3? Any link for example or tutorial with the answer will more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [`jqGrid`](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html). It also has [`helpers for ASP.NET MVC`](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx) that encapsulate most of the logic.

Comment: I looked at it, thought of using it but someone told me that its not free! Can I use it at production level without paying for the license?